# Validate Checkbox that has an array as name parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I used to validate checkbox form with a code like this:

```
<div>
  <form action="survey.php" method="post" name="survey"> 
  <span class="form"><input type="checkbox" name="event1" onClick="return countMarketing()">Event1</span>
  <span class"form"><input type="checkbox" name="event2" onClick="return countMarketing()">Event2</span>
  <span class"form"><input type="checkbox" name="event3" onClick="return countMarketing()">Event2</span>
  <!-- other forms -->
  </form>
</div>
```

And a javascript validation that is something like this (to limit the count of checkboxes checked):

```
function countMarketing() {

        var NewCountMarketing = 0

        if (document.survey.event1.checked)
        {NewCountMarketing = NewCountMarketing + 1}

        if (document.survey.event2.checked)
        {NewCountMarketing = NewCountMarketing + 1}

        if (document.survey.event3.checked)
        {NewCountMarketing = NewCountMarketing + 1}
        if (NewCountMarketing == 3)
        {
            alert('Please choose only two')
            document.survey; return false;
        }
    }
```

And validation like this works. But now, say im using php to for the submission, how do i check if in JS if the name of the form is something like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="events[]" id="event1" onClick="return countMarketing()">Event1
```

Ive tried to change the JS to:

```
if (document.survey.events[].checked)
    {code here}

if (document.survey.getElementByName('events[]').checked)
    {code here}

if (document.survey.getElementById('event1').checked)
    {code here}
```

But it doesnt work.. any can shed some light on me about this? thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You have the tag but no code for jQuery.

Comment: Did you try `document.survey["events[]"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in fact using jQuery you could do:

Make sure you are including jQuery in your document before you use this function & that the document is loaded before you try to run the function.

```
function countMarketing() {

  if( $('input[name="events[]"]').filter(':checked').length > 2 ) {
    alert('Please choose only two');
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have some jquery for some slides but I am really new to JS/jQuery and its also ok  if its a jQuery solution. Btw, I did try this but it doesn't seem to work atm, would it be because I also need to declare the form name? or will jQuery be able to work out by just the name of the input (say there are 5 checkbox inputs with the name `events[]`

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery included & that it is wrapped in $(function(){  <code-here>  }); otherwise it will execute before the document has fully loaded. With this you can have as many checkboxes as you like as long as they are named the same - no need for a form name.

Comment: @GitKidd I have updated my answer to show you how it would be used in your function

Comment: Great its working now, but how do I not allow the third box to proceed with a true value? meaning, after the alert pops up, the third box ticked is still checked, it should be that after the alert pops up, the 3rd tick is canceled.

Comment: @GitKidd OK, sorry. In that case you can do what is in this fiddle... http://jsbin.com/axales/5/ so whenever someone clicks on a checkbox - even if it is #2 and 2 others are check it will uncheck the one you clicked.

Comment: Wow brilliant! Thanks for the help @Precastic :) .. such a big help! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `inline events declaration` and move it to an `external Javascript file` or a `script block`

You can always use `bracket Notation` to access such attributes

```
document.survey["events[]"]
```

**Code**

```
    var elems = document.survey,
    checkboxNames = ["event1[]", "event2[]", "event3[]"];

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxNames.length; i++) {
    bindClick(elems[checkboxNames[i]]);
}

function bindClick(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', countMarketing);
}

function countMarketing() {

    var NewCountMarketing = 0
    var latest;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxNames.length; i++) {
        if (elems[checkboxNames[i]].checked) {
            latest = elems[checkboxNames[i]];
            NewCountMarketing++;
        }
    }

    if (NewCountMarketing == 3) {
        latest.checked = false;               
        alert('Please choose only two')
        document.survey;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLrKE/1/)**

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth! i will try this now, what would i need to change on the `checkboxNames` if say that I have 5 checkbox that has got the name `events[]` (for purposes of php form submission).

Comment: I checked the fiddle, how do I have the latest box unchecked once the alert pops up? because after the alert, the 3rd box value is still checked.

Comment: Just maintain an extra variable and set it to false when you check for the count. Check updated code